# Semi-naked lady in a transparent box full of needles which draw blood

Tags: story-identification, movie

My memory is hazy on this one as I watched it as a kid in early 80s. The scene I remember is a semi-naked woman in a transparent box or cube that has needles inside it. It closes in around her and draws out blood. I also remember it having space ship or space station in it.

Does anybody know what it was?

Comment: I've been searching for this one too but don't think it was any of the above. I remember it draining her too with needles. I remember something space like and desert too. I certainly have no memory of any of the above and don't believe it is. I think it darker in tone.

Answer (score 7):

[The Humanoid (1979)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080058/)

I think it's this! Hope it helps!

Comment: Star Wars really does have a lot to answer for, even aside from the prequels.

Comment: Thoughts: 1. For the love of Pete, can you frame a fricking shot? 2. If one Darth Vader is awesome, imagine how awesome twenty of them will be? 3. Richard Kiel's wife loves shoes.

Comment: The '70s were a hell of a drug

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be talking about a Cenobite Transformation Chamber in Hellraiser. Alternatively it might have been Event Horizon, which is a kind of Hellraiser in Space anyway.

Answer (score 2):

what about SpaceHunter: Adventures Beyond The Forbidden Zone?
It was a 3d movie from the late seventies. I only saw it the once- so this is a long shot- but do remember making lots of spike/needle related torture type stuff out of lego in response!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is [LifeForce](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089489/) but the UK poster was different than the one on IMDB so I'm not sure and I can't find a reference to the needles you mention.

Comment: Can't remember any needle boxes in LifeForce.

Comment: I saw it once, twenty five years ago, but I'm thinking that there was some sort of examination scene? I may be conflating it with another movie though and I'm certainly not watching it again no matter how nekkid Mathilda May gets

Comment: The movie Lifeforce (1985) would be my pick too, because it does involve a naked woman being locked in a transparent coffin.